# Update vnstat to 1.17

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, vnstat

How can I istall the latest version of vnstat (1.17)? I cannot find any instructions to compile or any repository or any deb file.

Comment: Try this [link](http://humdi.net/vnstat/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the old version of `vnstat`, then
Download the source code:

```
wget http://humdi.net/vnstat/vnstat-1.17.tar.gz
```

extract it:

```
tar -xzf ./vnstat-1.17.tar.gz
```

`cd` into its directory:

```
cd vnstat-1.17/
```

install `checkinstall` package:

```
sudo apt install checkinstall
```

compile the package:

```
./configure
make
```

install it using checkinstall:

```
sudo checkinstall
```

for removal use:

```
sudo dpkg -r vnstat
```